# Código esta pulando linhas - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de uma ajuda no meu projeto que busca palavras **(arquivo: Variaveis.txt)** dentro de de um outro arquivo **(Respostas.txt)** e faz a marcação se achar alguma palavra. Porem pulando algumas frases deixando em branco o texto final **(Resultado.txt)**.

Reduzi o tamanho das bases para facilitar o entendimento.

Código:

```
for i in range(1,23):

    arquivo = open('\Variaveis.txt', 'w')

    with open('\Respostas.txt') as stream:

        with open('\Resultado.txt') as arq:

            palavras = arq.readlines()

            for line in stream:

                    for word in palavras:

                        if word.lower() in line.lower():

                            a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n')

                            arquivo.writelines(a)
                            print(a)
                            break

arquivo.close()
```

Arquivos:
-Variáveis:

```
oi
mundo
alo
tchau
```

Respostas:

```
oi mundo
tchau vida solteira
ola meu amigos
mundo grande
```

Resultado:

```
oi mundo¬mundo

tchau vida solteira¬tchau
```

Resultado esperado:

```
oi mundo¬oi
tchau vida solteira¬tchau
ola meu amigos¬ola
mundo grande¬mundo
```

*Obs: Estava rodando o projeto escrevendo as variáveis dentro do código e funcionava igual ao resultado esperado, porem as bases são grandes e preciso usar as variáveis buscando dentro de um txt como esta no código acima.*

Comment: tem uns `'` em falta pelo código fora. Tem isso assim so na pergunta ou tem igual no seu código ?

Comment: desculpe, fui tirar informações do meu pc para postar aqui e tirei sem querer também os '
No Código esta correta esta parte.

Comment: uma dica paralela - tente pensar melhor os seus nomes de variáveis - você tem uma variável "arq" e uma variável "arquivo", ambas representando arquivos diferentes. Nada imprede que você chame as variáveis de "resultados, respostas, palavras"  - o programa ficaria muito mais fácil de ler.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é a leitura das palavras:

```
palavras = arq.readlines()
```

o método `readlines` retorna uma linha, inclusive com o \n no final. Da documentação:

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character (\n) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

Ou seja, seu código só casa quando a palavra está no final da frase buscada ou se ela for a ultima palavra do seu arquivo de palavras.

Para resolver isso, você deve remover o \n das palavras antes de buscá-las, usando o método `strip`. Algo como:

```
if word.strip().lower() in line.lower():
    a = (line.strip(), '¬', word + '\n')
    arquivo.writelines(a)
    print(a)
    break
```